# Embed FolderBrowserDialog into Form

Tags: c#, winforms, directory, folderbrowserdialog

How can I embed the FolderBrowserDialog into my "form1"? 
I don't want a popup dialog, how can I achieve this?

Comment: embed means exactly what you want to do? What all have you tried?

Comment: embed means that the control is **in** the form1, and not shown as a popupdialog, I tried the folderview control from http://www.ssware.com/megapack, this is exactly what I want, but I can't afford a license, because i'm still a student.

Comment: then i think you have to write your own code using basic controls like listbox, combox box, buttons etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement your own coding for doing  so. It is rather easy, you can use some `TreeView`s and `ListView`s and use `File` `Path` and other stuff from `System.IO` class.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to embed the FolderBrowserDialog in your own form, but you can use 3rd party controls like [Shell MegaPack](http://www.ssware.com/megapack.htm) to do this.

DISCLAIMER: I work for LogicNP Software, the developer of Shell MegaPack.

Comment: I tried out the Shell Megapack, it has some nice controls and i'd love to use them. But I am still a student and can't afford a license